# The word monitor in pactl list confused me

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I knew the concepts:sink and source in PulseAudio, clients can send audio to "sinks" and receive audio from "sources",So sinks are outputs (audio goes there), sources are inputs (audio comes from there),what is monitor then?

The below text is abstract from `pactl list`

```
Sink #11
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo
    Description: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB,   front-right: 50463 /  77% / -6.81 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC662 rev3 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC662 rev3 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfccc0000 irq 60"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:09:00.6"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:09:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC662 rev3"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0662,10ec0000,00100300"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9000, available)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9900, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-lineout
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #15
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 27537 /  42% / -22.59 dB,   front-right: 27537 /  42% / -22.59 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfccc0000 irq 60"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:09:00.6"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:09:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Get `Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor` from Sink #11.
Get `Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo` from Source #15.

1.Why `Monitor of Sink` is a kind of source ,instead `Monitor Source` is a kind of sink?
2.Can i write `Monitor Source` as `Monitor of Source`,vice verse ,Can i write `Monitor of Sink` as `Monitor Sink`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A monitor is a "child" source/sink associated with a particular "parent" sink/source, respectively.

A *monitor source* can be used to record a copy of the signal its parent *sink* is outputting.

A *monitor sink* could be used to output a copy of the signal that is being recorded by the parent *source*.

Your Sink #11 is `alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo`. It has this line in its description:

```
Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
```

Effectively, it says "This sink has a monitor source associated with it, and here is its name."

And then, the monitor source `alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor` has its own information block as your Source #15. That information block then has a corresponding line:

```
Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo
```

This points back into the "parent" sink device. It indicates the audio sink this source device is a **monitor of**.

Comment: The monitor source is the child of sink ,it watch source output.

Comment: The monitor sink is the child of source ,it watch sink input.

Answer (score 1):

In short *monitor* is a source you can use to direct output for a sink to another device.

Say you play ABBA on Audacious. Audacious produces samples which are read by the sink of analog-stereo output. (A source does not *send* data per se, it produces samples, and sinks read from sink inputs.)

Each time the sink reads a sample it also writes the sample to the *monitor*.

Now if you start Audacity, klick on the monitor meter (the meter beside the microphone). Then open `pavucontrol` under *capture from* you can select the *Monitor of XXX*.

Once that is done you can see the audio-meter in Audacity starts showing activity.

- https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_linux.html

Hence it *reads samples* from *monitor*. These samples are written by the sink reading from sink input; which are also written to the output of your headset.

---

- [Devices and streams](https://gavv.github.io/articles/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/#devices-and-streams)

```
                IN
>----------------------------------------->
             ,-- [source output]
  [source] --|
      |      '-- [source output]
      |                 |
      |                 |
   sample             sample
  producer           recorder
 (mic, ...)       (audacity, ...)
>------------------------------------------>
```

```
                OUT
>------------------------------------------>
 [sink input A] -.
                 +--> [sink] --> output + monitor
 [sink input B] -'      |           |
       |                |      the output device (speaker, ...)
       |                |              
 produces samples    consumes and mixes samples
    (mpv, ...)              (clocking, latency)
>------------------------------------------>
```

From [PulseAudio under the hood](https://gavv.github.io/articles/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/#object-hierarchy)

> Every sink automatically gets a sink monitor, named as “<sink_name>.monitor”. Every time when the sink reads a chunk from its sink inputs, it also writes this chunk to the sink monitor.

so; each time pulseaudio reads from the sink input for

```
alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo
```

it also writes that data to the monitor sink

```
alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
```